# How to reset user specific variables in Streamer.Bot?

Tags: twitch.tv

I am trying to reset or clear all the user specific variables I have set for users in my twitch chat.

My goal is to build an on-screen poll that chatters can interact with by typing a number. I have it mostly figured out, but my sticking point is the method I used to make it so I only record one vote from each chatter. When they vote, I assign them a user specific variable "voted", and use an if statement at the beginning of the action to check for that variable.

The problem is that in order to do a second poll I need to dump these variables, or reset their value. I've found a workaround by setting the variables as non-persistant, and then restarting streamer.bot, but I was hoping someone out there has found a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a better work around. Instead of using a fixed value to check the "voted" user specific variables, I made another variable called "pollNo" which increments every time I make a new poll. I hope this helps someone out there.